# How to load balance with WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, performance

I am setting up a desktop WPF application with my BLL running as a WCF service on a separate application server. I'd like to set up a server farm and load balance the BLL. What is the recommended method to accomplish this? Does WCF include any features that help with load balancing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't say there are specific WCF features for load balancing, however you certainly can load balance WCF services using hardware or software load balancing approaches.

Depending on the binding that you are using you may need to change the default binding settings.  Microsoft has more details in their article on WCF [Load Balancing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx) where they discuss settings for NetTcpBinding, WSHttpBinding, WSDualHttpBinding, and BasicHttpBinding.